# Guacamole ssh into localhost Config

Tags: ssh, apache2

So I installed the apache guacamole and got the tightvnc service, which is also on the same machine as guac to connect and work perfectly.

Problem is when I try to set up a connection for a ssh into the local machine, 127.0.0.1 didn't work. Nor if I enetered the actual ip of the server.

The fields like key and key passphrase are provided correctly. And the user (not root) without and with a password has also been tried.

What could have gone wrong? My guess is do I have to somehow enable the localhost connection in the config of sshd or use my linode's internal ip address?

Ps. my vps sshd cofig does not allow password nor root log in.

Comment: Was SSH support marked as "Yes" when you were installing Guacamole? Please show a part of your config or the error message you get when connecting to SSH. If you have disabled using passwords for logging in, then you can use Private Keys for the connection.

Answer (score 0):

So it is actually that I have to enable password authentication for localhost addresses in the sshd config in order for this to work, in order for a key to work I will need to add a PEM header when generating!